# Borel-measurability of graph(f)

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, complex-analysis, analysis, measure-theory

If we suppose $f:R\to R$ is a continuous function. I need to show: $\lambda^2(graph(f))=0,$ where $graph(f):={(x,y)\in R^2 :y=f(x)}$.

In general, I think I need to prove the Borel-measurability of graph(f), but I am not sure where to begin especially what is the graph(f) part mean. I anyone has any sources, hints or anything it would be amazing!

Comment: This is an easy consequence of Fubini's Theroem and it has been answered before.

Comment: Borel measurability is obvious since the graph is a closed set.

Comment: I think I am missing something, but I don't really see the connection between the suggested and my question

Comment: Continuous functions are measurable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $h(x,y)=y-x,\ k:\mathbb{R}^{2}\to\mathbb{R}^{2}$ maps $(x,y)$ to $(f(x),y)$. Then for any $A\times B\subset\mathbb{R}^{2},\ k^{-1}(A\times B)=f^{-1}(A)\times B\in\mathcal{B}_{\mathbb{R^{2}}}$. But $h$ is continuous and $g=h\circ k$, we have $\mathrm{graph}(f)=g^{-1}(0)$ Borel-measurable.